# Cache keeps making users go to my old web url

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, web

My home page used to be www.example.com/index.html, because I was on the Weebly platform. I then switched to Wordpress, where the home page should simply be www.example.com/home.

However, I realized if I visit the URL on a browser where cache hasn't been cleared for the past 24 hours, the website automatically redirects the user to www.example.com/index.**html**. Is there a way to fix this? I've Googled ways for about 2 hours and tried various Wordpress plugins...

Comment: clear cache and reload?

Comment: The issue is visitors who have visited my old URL may not clear their cache.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a redirect](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/) in your wordpress site from /home.html to /home

Comment: Tried doing that, browser still redirects to the .html page.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete old index.html and add this to your .htaccess file in root

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.com/home
```

Comment: This gave me a "page load error", saying it redirected too many times.